# How can I scrape this recipe?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to webscrape some recipes for my own personal collection. It works great on some sites because the website structure sometimes easily allows for scraping, but some are harder. This one I have no idea how to deal with:

https://www.koket.se/halloumigryta-med-tomat-linser-och-chili

For the moment, let's just assume I want the ingredients on the left. If I inspect the website it looks like what I want are the two `article class="ingredients"` chunks. But I can't seem to get there.

[image]

I start with the following:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
read_html("https://www.koket.se/halloumigryta-med-tomat-linser-och-chili") %>%
  html_nodes(".recipe-column-wrapper") %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="react-recipe-page"]')
```

However, running the above code shows that all of the ingredients are stored in `data-item` like so:

```
<div id="react-recipe-page" data-item="{
   "chefNames":"<a href='/kockar/siri-barje'>Siri Barje</a>",
   "groupedIngredients":[{
      "header":"Kokosris",
      "ingredients":[{
         "name":"basmatiris","unit":"dl","amount":"3","amount_info":{"from":3},"main":false,"ingredient":true
      }
      <<<and so on>>>
```

So I am a little bit puzzled, because from inspecting the website everything seems to be neatly placed in things I can extract, but now it's not. Instead, I'd need some serious regular expressions in order to get everything like I want it.

So my question is: am I missing something? Is there some way I can get the contents of the `ingredients` articles?

(I tried SelectorGadget, but it just gave me `No valid path found`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract attributes by using `html_attr("data-item")` from the `rvest` package.

Furthermore, the data-item attribute looks like it's in JSON, which you can convert to a list using the `fromJSON` from the `jsonlite` package:

```
html <- read_html("https://www.koket.se/halloumigryta-med-tomat-linser-och-chili") %>%
  html_nodes(".recipe-column-wrapper") %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="react-recipe-page"]')

recipe <- html %>% html_attr("data-item") %>% 
  fromJSON
```

Lastly, the `recipe` list contains lots of different values, which are not relevant, but the ingredients and measurements are there as well in the element `recipe$ingredients`.

Comment: Wow, that was even better than I was hoping for. Thanks!